# Swift array of dictionaries with multiple types without using NSDictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2

I have been working with an array of dictionaries in Swift (version 7 beta 4) using NSDictionary.  The array is a collection of fmdb results which contain differing data types.  I would like to end up with an array of native swift dictionaries in order to use the filter functionality of swift collection types. The following is a snippet of the query function I'm using the create the array:

```
class func query(sql:String) -> [NSDictionary] {
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String
    let databasePath:String = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myDB.db")
    let db = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    var resultsArray:[NSDictionary] = []

    if db.open() {

        let results:FMResultSet? = db.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        while (results?.next() == true) {
            resultsArray.append(results!.resultDictionary()) //appending query result

        }
        db.close()

    } else {
        print("Error: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
    return resultsArray
}
```

I tried using AnyObject such as:

```
    class func query(sql:String) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String
    let databasePath:String = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Kerbal.db")
    let db = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    var resultsArray:[[String:AnyObject]] = []

    if db.open() {

        let results:FMResultSet? = db.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        while (results?.next() == true) {
            resultsArray.append(results!.resultDictionary() as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)

        }
        db.close()

    } else {
        print("Error: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
    return resultsArray
}
```

however I can't use the filter such as `resultsArray.filter({$0["fieldName"] == "part"})` with `AnyObject`.

My question: Is it possible to create this array with native Swift dictionaries even though the dictionaries have different types? Could the new protocol extension be used on collection type to solve this problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you know exactly which types are in the dictionary? The documentation  (which is in obj-c) doesn't say something about that.

Comment: I know for instance that three of the values in each dictionary will be Strings while the others are Double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know which objects you are dealing with you have to use filter like so:

```
resultsArray.filter{ ($0["fieldName"] as? String) == "part"}
```

So you optionally cast the value to the desired type and compare it.

Note: I'm using the trailing closure syntax.

As suggestion I would use a tuple of different arrays which hold dictionaries:

```
// some dummy values
let resultsArray: [[String : AnyObject]] = [["Hi" : 3], ["Oh" : "String"]]

var result = (doubles: [[String : Double]](), strings: [[String : String]]())

// going through all dictionaries of type [String : AnyObject]
for dict in resultsArray {

    // using switch and pattern matching to cast them (extensible for more types)
    // you have to up cast the dictioanary in order to use patten matching
    switch dict as AnyObject {
    case let d as [String : Double]: result.doubles.append(d)
    case let s as [String : String]: result.strings.append(s)
    default: fatalError("unexpected type")
    }
}

return result
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do and I may not have been clear about the types I have...Its not that I might have a dictionary with all strings in one case and in another case have a dictionary with all doubles.  rather I have dictionaries similar to  dictArray = [[name:bob, age:25], [name:bill, age:30]].  By default it would be impossible to create this array of dictionaries with a native swift dictionary because all the types have to be the same.  At least thats my understanding.

Comment: In this case I would use tuples if you have only a few different types. So the return type would be `(doubles: [[String : Double]], strings: [[String : String]])`. If you want I would also add an example to my answer how to do that.

Comment: So in my case where my dictionary is an fmdb result,  You would loop through the values of the dictionary and determine the type and then save the key-value to either the doubles or strings element of the tuple?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I haven't had time to try it but I think this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably adopt the Equatable protocol, not all AnyObjects are such in fact, and so no comparison and thereafter filtering may be done.